# @PreAuthorize on spring controller sending redirect if authorization fails

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got spring security successfully evaluating a @PreAuthorize on my controller.  If i use "permitAll" then I can view the page, and if I use "isAuthenticated()" then I get an ugly Access is Denied stack trace.  If I put the configuration in an intercept-url within the http node in my security context configuration xml file then I am nicely redirected to the login page instead of getting the nasty stack trace right in my page.

Is there a way for me to get the redirection with the annotation mechanism only?

Comment: Why is having this in the security context file is not sufficient?

Comment: I'm just trying to reduce the amount of places I have to edit in order to create a new url handler.  Currently, I have to edit my controller class, my context configuration xml, and the tuckey's urlrewrite configuration .xml.  This isn't a deal breaker or anything, but if I can bring it down to two locations instead of three, it'll be that much easier next time.  If I'm honest, it was more of a curiosity on my part as to whether or not I could use method level security on controller RequestMappings without losing functionality.

Comment: I don't think this is possible as it can't tell the difference between a failure due to not being logged in at all and a failure due to not having the right privilege.  Would love to be wrong though if someone knows a way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to work.  There were a couple of things I had to deal with.

First, my Spring MVC configuration had a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver with a defaultErrorView configured.  That was intercepting the Authentication and Authorization errors before they could get to the access-denied-handler that I had configured in the http element in my security configuration.  The final code looks something like this.

securitycontext.xml

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<!-- HTTP security configurations -->
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler" />
    ... other configuration here ...
</http>

<!-- handler for authorization failure.  Will redirect to the login page. -->
<beans:bean id="myAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <beans:property name="errorPage" value="/index" />
</beans:bean>
```

note that the loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint is actually not a part of the solution, it's the access-denied-handler.

my mvc-config.xml still has the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver, but with no defaultErrorView configured.  If I were to continue with this path, I would probably implement my own SimpleMappingExceptionResolver that would let Authentication and Authorization excpetions pass through, OR configure it in the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver instead.

The killer in this deal is that I haven't found a way to configure the requires-channel="https" from the intercept-url through an annotation, so I'll be putting it in the xml configuration file for now anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize your error handling by overriding the security entry point.  All exceptions that happen in the filter chain (defined by the mapping you define in the web.xml file) for secure objects get caught and can be handled there.  If they are not handled then the ExceptionTranslationFilter will take over.

You can define your own entry point like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (authException != null) {
            // you can check for the spefic exception here and redirect like this
            response.sendRedirect("403.html");
        }
    }
}
```

You can specify this as your entry point by setting this as you entry point in the xml config file:

```
<http entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint">

  ...

</http>
```

In your specific case the PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter will be invoked by whatever AccessDecisionManager you specify in your configuration (typically it is one of the following: AffirmativeBased, ConsensusBased, or UnanimousBased).  You will see that these Voters throw the AccessDeniedException which you can specifically catch and handle in your entry point.

Grant